# Pandas - converting datetime64 to Period

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Series of dates in datetime64 format.

I want to convert them to a series of Period with a monthly frequency. (Essentially, I want to group dates into months for analytical purposes).

There must be a way of doing this - I just cannot find it quickly.

Note: these dates are not the index of the data frame - they are just a column of data in the data frame.

Example input data (as a Series)

```
data = pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(['2014-10-01', '2014-10-01', '2014-10-31', '2014-11-15', '2014-11-30', np.NaN, '2014-12-01']))
print (data)
```

My current kludge/work around looks like

```
data = pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(['2014-10-01', '2014-10-01', '2014-10-31', '2014-11-15', '2014-11-30', np.NaN, '2014-01-01']))
data = pd.DatetimeIndex(data).to_period('M')
data = pd.Series(data.year).astype('str') + '-' +  pd.Series((data.month).astype('int')).map('{:0>2d}'.format)
data = data.where(data != '2262-04', other='No Date')
print (data)
```

Comment: what exact output do you want?

Comment: I have added a kludge that gets towards what I am after ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Their are some issues currently (even in master) dealing with `NaT` in `PeriodIndex`, so your approach won't work like that. But seems that you simply want to resample; so do this. You can of course specify a function for `how` if you want.

```
In [57]: data
Out[57]: 
0   2014-10-01
1   2014-10-01
2   2014-10-31
3   2014-11-15
4   2014-11-30
5          NaT
6   2014-12-01
dtype: datetime64[ns]

In [58]: df = DataFrame(dict(A = data, B = np.arange(len(data))))

In [59]: df.dropna(how='any',subset=['A']).set_index('A').resample('M',how='count')
Out[59]: 
            B
A            
2014-10-31  3
2014-11-30  2
2014-12-31  1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   import pandas as pd
   import numpy as np
   datetime import datetime
   data = pd.to_datetime(
   pd.Series(['2014-10-01', '2014-10-01', '2014-10-31', '2014-11-15', '2014-11-30', np.NaN, '2014-01-01']))
   data=pd.Series(['{}-{:02d}'.format(x.year,x.month) if isinstance(x, datetime) else "Nat" for x in pd.DatetimeIndex(data).to_pydatetime()])


0    2014-10
1    2014-10
2    2014-10
3    2014-11
4    2014-11
5        Nat
6    2014-01
dtype: object
```

Best I could come up with, if the only non datetimes objects possible are floats you can change `if isinstance(x, datetime)` to `if not isinstance(x, float)`

Comment: Thanks - while tighter than mine - not really a pandas.Period type. Also, the months to September are single digit.

Comment: @MarktheGraph, I fixed the padding, in  my answer the types are the same as yours, I presumed that would be ok.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`data.dt.to_period('M')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html)